# Allow S3 bucket operations based on EC2 role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, acl

Our EC2s are secured using IAM roles. When trying to run an AWS console command such as `aws s3 cp` I am seeing:

```
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

If allowed based on specific users that are given keys, there are no issues. This just isn't working with roles.

Here is the bucket ACL:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Public",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Devs",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/DevUser"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/something-privileged/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "EC2s",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/EC2Role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/something-privileged/*"
        },
    ]
}
```

As you can see, we want the public to generally be able to fetch objects that we link to. This works.

We want devs to be able to access a specific hidden folder in the bucket using their AWS keys. This works.

We want EC2s to be able to run aws-cli commands on that same hidden folder using only the assigned security role. This does not work.

I also tried `"Effect": "Deny", "NotPrincipal": { ... }` on the EC2 statement but that didn't work either.

What's wrong with this ACL?

Comment: Independently of the deny issue, you generally don't provide IAM roles with access to S3 resources in the way you have done it. You generally add the S3 permissions/resources to the IAM role, rather than add the role and the permissions/resources to the S3 bucket policy.

Comment: Yes, the general rule is: If providing access to "everybody", use a Bucket Policy. If providing access to specific IAM Users, Roles or Groups, then put the permissions on that IAM User/Role/Group.

Comment: The `EC2Role` role already has full access to S3 but still gets 403 forbidden for EC2s which are assigned that role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `Deny` statement in this where the principal is not that specific IAM user. In any AWS privilege a [deny will always override an allow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html) which is the scenario happening here.

To allow this here you will need to [include the IAM role arn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-1) in the `NotPrincipal` statement as well. This would look like the below statement.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Public",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Devs",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/DevUser", "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/EC2Role"]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/something-privileged/*"
        }
    ]
}
```